# AIOKafka: Formerly working code now fails at send_and_wait

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-asyncio

I have been using AIOKafka for some time, I had no problems with it, until today.

Strange `TypeError` shows up when I try to send a message using `AIOKafkaProducer.send_and_wait`. I also posted this question as issue on AIOKafka's github repository, but it looks like they are kind of inactive. Maybe here someone can help me.

here is the code:

```
import asyncio
from aiokafka import AIOKafkaConsumer, AIOKafkaProducer

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
producer = AIOKafkaProducer(loop=loop, bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092")

async def _initialize(prod, future):
    await prod.start()
    await prod.send_and_wait("main_topic", str.encode("hello!!"))

future = asyncio.Future()
task = asyncio.ensure_future(_initialize(producer, future))
loop.run_until_complete(task)
print("loop ended!")
loop.close()
```

here is the error message I get:

```
yilmazali@yilmazali:~$ python3 aiokafkatest.py
Unexpected error in sender routine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiokafka/producer/producer.py", line 374, in _sender_routine
    task.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiokafka/producer/producer.py", line 418, in _send_produce_req
    response = yield from self.client.send(node_id, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiokafka/client.py", line 415, in send
    request, expect_response=expect_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiokafka/conn.py", line 165, in send
    message = header.encode() + request.encode()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/util.py", line 159, in __call__
    return self.method()(self.target(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/struct.py", line 42, in _encode_self
    [self.__dict__[name] for name in self.SCHEMA.names]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 132, in encode
    for i, field in enumerate(self.fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 132, in <listcomp>
    for i, field in enumerate(self.fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 170, in encode
    [self.array_of.encode(item) for item in items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 170, in <listcomp>
    [self.array_of.encode(item) for item in items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 132, in encode
    for i, field in enumerate(self.fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 132, in <listcomp>
    for i, field in enumerate(self.fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 170, in encode
    [self.array_of.encode(item) for item in items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 170, in <listcomp>
    [self.array_of.encode(item) for item in items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 132, in encode
    for i, field in enumerate(self.fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 132, in <listcomp>
    for i, field in enumerate(self.fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/types.py", line 93, in encode
    return Int32.encode(len(value)) + value
TypeError: object of type '_io.BytesIO' has no len()
```

I did no changes in my kafka structure or libraries. My kafka broker looks fine. I can produce/consume messages with shell scripts.

I had no problems with AIOKafka for the last 2-3 months, the code above worked fine. Out of nowhere, this error showed up and I'm wondering what the problem is.

Any help will be appreciated.

With kindest regards,

Ali

--

update: We ran this code segment on a friend's computer, it worked fine. I advertised my kafka to outside and she successfully wrote to my local kafka topic with the code above. AIOKafka library versions are 0.4.0 on both machines. Also asyncio versions are 3.4.3 on both machines. In short, the problem is not about my kafka or libraries. Something is wrong with my machine but god knows what specifically causes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked on my machine. I simply uninstalled and installed `aiokafka` module.

Although I am not satisfied with this solution and I would like to venture deeper to the heart of problem, I'm glad I can continue doing my work now.

Hope this helps to fellow strangers with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you've updated kafka-python to version higher than 1.3.5. I did so and aiokafka started failing. I returned at kafka-python 1.3.5 and it seemed OK